# What is the meaning of keycode '\x03'?

Tags: key

I am making a keylogger that logs each keystroke in a file. I am wondering what the character code '\x03' means. Is it a KeyboardInterrupt?

Comment: https://donsnotes.com/tech/charsets/ascii.html says hex 03 is ascii for end of text. How often does this character appear in your code?